# Efficient conversion from Java arrays through JNI to/from ALGLIB real arrays

Tags: java, arrays, java-native-interface, alglib

I need to convert one-dimensional and two-dimensional Java arrays of `double` elements through JNI to/from the ALGLIB `real_1d_array` and `real_2d_array` in C/C++, respectively. Right now, the process is as follows:

1. Use the JNI `GetDoubleArrayElements()` to obtain a contiguous vector of `jdouble` in C/C++. On my machine, this always produces a copy, i.e. JNI sets the last argument of this call, `jboolean isCopy`, to `JNI_TRUE`.
2. Allocate a C/C++ vector of `double` and copy elements from the JNI vector of `jdouble` to it. Note that, in general, there is no guarantee that the `jdouble` type is the same as the `double` type, so a cast to `double` is necessary when copying array elements one by one. (Is there a clean way to determine that `jdouble` is indeed the same as `double`, either at compile time or runtime?)
3. Instantiate an ALGLIB `real_1d_array` or `real_2d_array`, respectively. As far as I can tell from the ALGLIB code, this creates an `ae_matrix` of dimensions (0, 0) internally held by the array.
4. Copy the array elements from the C/C++ contiguous vector of `double` to the ALGLIB array using the `setcontent()` method. As far as I can tell from the code, this resizes the internallly-held `ae_matrix` appropriately and copies elements one by one into that matrix. It looks like in the case of a two-dimensional matrix, the first dimension is a vector of pointers to linear vectors of `double`, so that elements are stored non-contiguously in an array of one-dimensional arrays (similar to Java).
5. Use ALGLIB to perform the desired computations using the real arrays.
6. To copy results back to JAVA arrays through JNI, reverse the process. Elements of the ALGLIB real arrays are only accessible through methods. For one-dimensional arrays, there is a `getcontent()` method that returns a pointer to a contiguous vector of `double`. For two-dimensional array, through `operator []` that returns a pointer to a contiguous row. As before a one-by-one element copy with a cast to `jdouble` is used.

As you can see, there is plenty of copying involved. For small arrays, this is not a big deal, but for larger ones this gets quite expensive in terms of memory and CPU.

Is there a way to speed things up without relying on the knowledge of internal structures of ALGLIB, which may be subject to change?